# Why do some files become corrupt when written from byte[] array

Tags: c#, winforms

I am retrieving mp4 clips via a `REST API` for a security camera. The clips are 2-5 seconds long and are almost always less than 600 KB.

The info for the clips is populated into a DataGridView, and that info includes the `URI` for the REST API. I get the `byte[]` array via the API, write it to a file, and then play it through windows media player. About 20% of the clips are corrupt, but they are always exactly 919 bytes when they are. I can't figure out why this is happening.

I know the URI isn't invalid, because `Blink.GetClipAsync(uri, user.getToken());` would throw an exception.

Am I doing something wrong that could cause this?

```
    private async void ClipView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        String uri = "";
        int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
        try
        {
              uri = ClipView.Rows[rowIndex].Tag.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        String fileName = Path.GetFileName(uri);
        byte[] mp4 = await Blink.GetClipAsync(uri, user.getToken());
        String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        String pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Blink Desktop");
        String filePathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, fileName);
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);         
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePathString))
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePathString, mp4);
        }        
        Properties.Settings.Default.currentClipSelection = filePathString;
        var ClipPlayer = new Clip_Player();
        ClipPlayer.Show();
    }


        public async Task<byte[]> GetClipAsync(String url, String token)
        {
            byte[] response;
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {

                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), Properties.Settings.Default.RegionAPI + url))
                {
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("token-auth", token);
                    HttpContent content = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result.Content;
                    response = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Comment: You haven't explained what `Blink` is? I can't google it with the `.GetClipAsync()` method. That's obviously the problem, even through  the URL is correct for some reason that method only returns 919 bytes 20% of the time.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I added that method to my question.

Comment: Note that you have `if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePathString))`. So, if you downloaded a faulty file, you're not overwriting it with the new bytes you have already (allegedly) downloaded. This: `if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString))` is also not needed, you can call `Directory.CreateDirectory()` even if the path already exists. -- About the API call: try to open a faulty file in Notepad, see what the content is. -- Using, `TryAddWithoutValidation()`, you're supposed to check whether the method succeeded. `...content = httpClient.SendAsync().Result.Content;` is just wrong.

Comment: This supposing that the User can click a Cell content once and not fire double clicks once in a while (or constantly).

Comment: @Jimi thanks for the help, updated what you suggested. I opened the file in notepad. It's a 403 error that says `Request blocked.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.` I don't own the website, and the API is unofficial, so now I'm trying to figure out how to handle that.